# how to write mod_rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am in the process of redirecting some urls to specific page using mod_rewrite in htaccess file. The project is developed in core PHP(no frameworks) and i'm working on xampp server,

Ex: I want the following url to be redirected to test.php

```
localhost/project/any_string //should be redirected to test.php
localhost/project/any_string/test //should be redirected to new_test.php
```

And

```
localhost/project/any_string.php //should be redirected to any_string.php only
localhost/project/any_string/any_string.php //should be redirected to any_string/any_string.php only
```

I have mod_rewrite enabled, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 'RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+) test.php [L,NC]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you need, this will do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)project/(.*)/(.*).php$ /$2/$3.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)project/(.*).php$ /$2.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)project/(.*)test$ /new_test.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)project/(.*)$ /test.php [L,R=301]
```

By the way, the order of the rules here is very important, so you have to keep it exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the following?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule localhost/project/(.*)/test new_test.php [R]
RewriteRule localhost/project/(.*) test.php [R]
RewriteRule localhost/project/(.*)/(.*).php $1/$2.php [R]
RewriteRule localhost/project/(.*).php $1.php [R]
```

The [R] flag forces a Redirect.
Note that longer matches are listed before shorter ones (otherwise the longer matches would never be matched.)

Comment: i have tried your solution, but it's not working for me

Comment: What directory have you placed the .htaccess file in, and have you got AllowOverride set in the parent vhost ?

Comment: I don't think @avinashhiremath is looking for a redirect. The intention here, I'm sure, is for an internal rewrite to the PHP file. Also, you've included `localhost` in the rewrite pattern, which is invalid.

Comment: I have placed .htaccess in project directory and i have set Allowoverride All in httpd-xampp.conf

Comment: @Mike, i'm looking to redirect `localhost/project/any_string` to `localhost/project/test.php`

Comment: @avinashhiremath - Oh okay, my apologies. Many folks get confused by the words 'rewrite' and 'redirect'.